# Proof of Green's theorem under assumption of only type 1 curve.

Tags: calculus, greens-theorem

The proof of Green's theorem on Stewart's calculus book has assumption of the closed curve being both type 1 and type 2.
Can one prove the theorem under assumption of being only type 1? Are there simple proof for this?

Comment: Wikipedia does this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Comment: Whatever type 1 and type 2 mean, if in this book the formula has been proven for type 1 and type 2 curves, it is a fortiori proven for type 1 curves alone.